# Copy column value only when other column is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked a question in an interview about the following kind of output:

```
Id  A       B        C
1   a       b      (insert value of B) 
2   a      NULL    (insert value of A)
3 NULL     NULL    (insert 'X')
```

I am bit of New in SQL ,I am trying this, but haven't implemented it correctly so far. This is what I have:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from #tbl where A IS NOT NULL) 
    IF EXISTS(select * from #tbl where B is not null)
        UPDATE #tbl SET C =B
    ELSE
        UPDATE #tbl SET C =A
ELSE
    IF EXISTS(select * from #tbl where B IS NULL)
    UPDATE #tbl SET C ='X'
```

I also want to remove if "else" Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: yes . i explored my question more ...I want to do it with case switch

Answer (score 4):

The coalesce operator is just done to find the "next not null value".

```
update #tbl
set C = coalesce(B, A, 'X')
```

assuming B, A are Varchar or assimilated...

Comment: Case gives you a more possibilities, but I really do like your solution.  Elegant!

Comment: @AnthonyHorne well, yes, as stated in doc : `the COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression`. But it's an ANSI shorcut, which is also fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement together with isnull.  Something along the lines of:

```
update #tbl
set C = 
case 
    when A is not null THEN  A
    when B is not null THEN  B
    else                     'X'
end
```

Comment: thanks for auggestion . but it gives Column C output like C
b
NULL
X

Comment: @user3487944 well, it's just that the order is wrong : `when B is not null then B` then `when A is not null then A`

Answer (score 1):

with three update

```
update table set c = 'X' where a is null and b is null and c is null
update table set c = b where (not a is null) and not (b is null) and c is null
update table set c = a where (not a is null) and b is null and c is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ISNULL:

```
update tbl 
set C=
ISNULL(ISNULL(B, A), 'X')
```

using case

```
update tbl
set C = 
case 
    when A is not null and B IS not null THEN  B
    when A is not null and B IS null THEN  A
    else 'X'
end
```

Comment: yes thats How i wanted to do .. thanks .. coalesce() is also something New what i learned here ..

Comment: Yeah, update using coalesce is the best answer and way..., Learn more about that.